# Add new element under specific element category in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, element, addition

Edit 2: It seems I got the persistance of the changes wrong.
It will simply record the new elements for the last record in the csv file.
How do I keep the added elements after they are added in the xml tree?

#########edit end#########

Edit:
After running the code from furas, I can achieve what I want. With some caveats:

my cvs is

```
orderid,price,tax,gift
1,23.00,0.00,false
```

Order 1's first product is already in xml.
Script will add the second product in the xml.

If I add 3rd product

```
orderid,price,tax,gift
1,23.00,0.00,false
1,44.00,0.00,false
```

and run it again the third product is not added.
Moreover if I change the price from 23.00 to 55.00 and run it, the price in xml remains 23.00.
Is this some cache? Running on linux mint. Very odd.
My code is:

```
from lxml import etree
import io

csv=open('orders_export (4).csv').readlines()

    for i in csv[1:]:
        
        P=i.split(',')
        
        if len(P[2])==0:
            
            orderid=P[0]
            tree = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(allxml.encode()))
            root = tree.getroot()
            items=root.find('.//{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31}order[@order-no="#PRIME1036"]{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31}product-lineitems')
            
            new_item = etree.SubElement(items, 'product-lineitem')
    
            net_price = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'net_price')
            net_price.text = P[18]
    
            tax = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'tax')
            tax.text = '0.0'
    
            net_price2 = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'gross-price')
            net_price2.text = P[18]
    
            tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
            c+=1
    
    tree.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

################# end edit###################

I have a xml file showing some store orders.

Each order only has 1 product at the moment. I.e. order1 - 1 pair of jeans. Order2 - 1 ball.

Some of the orders actually have more than one product.
I have a csv with the extra products, per order.
I am stuck how can I add the extra products per order.

My xml look like this:

```
     ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <orders xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
                
        <order order-no="#PRIME1036">
            
             <product-lineitems>
                <product-lineitem>
                            <net-price>29.99</net-price>
                            <tax>0.83</tax>                
                            <gift>false</gift>
                  </product-lineitem>
               
                    </product-lineitems>
    </order>
<order>
.
..
```

Any idea how can I add the extra product(s) under  for the specific order-no attribute #PRIME1036?
I.e. select the order number by the attribute, find the element and add subelements under it?

I need to get:

```
 <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>29.99</net-price>
                    <tax>0.83</tax>                
                    <gift>false</gift>
          </product-lineitem>
<product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>999.99</net-price>
                    <tax>0</tax>                
                    <gift>false</gift>
          </product-lineitem>
       
            </product-lineitems>
```

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Do you know modules for `xml` like [lxml](https://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) ? If you don't know them then maybe it would be better to find some tutorial.

Comment: If the answer from furas makes you achieve what you want (that is what you wrote), mark the answer as accepted. If you need help with "caveats", please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Python has special modules to work with XML

- standard [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) (xml.dom, xml.etree)
- [lxml](https://lxml.de/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

You can read from file `root = etree.parse(filename).getroot()` or use string `root = etree.fromstring(text.encode())`

`lxml` uses `XPATH` to search elements.

(because your file has `xmlns="..."` so `find()` needs `namespace` or you would have to search `{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31}order` and `{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31}product-lineitems' instead of` order`and`product-lineitems`)

Next you can use `SubElement(element, tag)` (or `element.append(Element(tag))` to add tag, and `.text` to add text in this tag.

And finally you can use `etree.tostring(root)` to generate string or `etree.ElementTree(root).write(filename)` to write in file.

```
text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
   <order order-no="#PRIME1036">
      <product-lineitems>
         <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>29.99</net-price>
            <tax>0.83</tax>                
            <gift>false</gift>
         </product-lineitem>
      </product-lineitems>
   </order>
</orders>'''

from lxml import etree
import io

#root = etree.fromstring(text.encode())  # I have to encode because xml has declared `encoding="UTF-8"`

#tree = etree.parse(filename)
tree = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(text.encode()))  # I have to encode because xml has declared `encoding="UTF-8"`
root = tree.getroot()

print('nsmap:', root.nsmap)

# find element
items = root.find(f'.//order[@order-no="#PRIME1036"]/product-lineitems', namespaces=root.nsmap)

# add new subelement
new_item = etree.SubElement(items, 'product-lineitem')

net_price = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'net_price')
net_price.text = '999.99'

tax = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'tax')
tax.text = '0'

gift = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'gift')
gift.text = 'false'

print('\n--- result ---\n')

# `tostring(..., pretty_print=True)` doesn't work when items added to old XML
# `write(..., pretty_print=True)` doesn't work when items added to old XML

etree.indent(root, space="   ")  # to reformat it (because `pretty_print` doesn't work when items added to old XML

print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8').decode())

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<orders xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
   <order order-no="#PRIME1036">
      <product-lineitems>
         <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>29.99</net-price>
            <tax>0.83</tax>
            <gift>false</gift>
         </product-lineitem>
         <product-lineitem>
            <net_price>999.99</net_price>
            <tax>0</tax>
            <gift>false</gift>
         </product-lineitem>
      </product-lineitems>
   </order>
</orders>
```

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for the code. However when I try to run it, it compains about syntax erro on line 26: items = root.find(f'.//order[@order-no="#PRIME1036"]/product-lineitems',namespaces=root.nsmap). Python higlites the ' in lineitems'. What might be the issue?

Comment: code works for me without problem. Do you get `error message` or only `highlight`. `highlight` is NOT error but only IDE's warning and it can be mistake in IDE. First run code to see if you get real error message

Comment: It must be something to do with version of python. I am using 2.7.12. I used the long string to do the find and it works.

Comment: @vas: Do you really have to use Python 2? That version of Python is obsolete and unsupported.